# Need to summarize a dynamic xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath

I have a far too large dynamic xpath and would like to know if there is a shortened version that can be used.  This is for a legend to a chart object, "Campaign Response" (which cannot be found by contains(text(), as it is embedded within the chart and isn't recognized as a string.)  There are 4 locations of "Campaign Response" at different locations on different charts on the same screen.

I've tried using dynamic (//) body//section//div etc, and tend to wind up with something that grabs multiple objects.

```
//body[contains(@class,'desktop')]
/div[contains(@class,'desktop container forceStyle oneOne 
   lafStandardLayoutContainer lafAppLayoutHost forceAccess forceStyle 
   oneOne')]
/div[contains(@class,'viewport')]
/section[contains(@class,'stage panelSlide hasFixedFooter')]
/div[@id='brandBand_1']
/div[contains(@class,'slds-template__container')]
/div[contains(@class,'center oneCenterStage lafSinglePaneWindowManager')]
/div[contains(@class,'windowViewMode-normal oneContent active lafPageHost')]
/div[contains(@class,'container homeLanding')]
/div[contains(@class,'flexipagePage')]
/div[contains(@class,'responsiveContents homeDesktopTemplate')]
/div[contains(@class,'colMain')]
/div[contains(@class,'bottomWrapper')]
/div[contains(@class,'bottomLeft')]
/div[4]
/article[1]
/div[2]
/div[1]
/div[1]
/div[1]
/div[1]
/div[2]
/div[1]
/div[2]
/div[1]
/div[1]
```

html snippet - DIV CLASS="PS-CONTAINER" DATA-PS-ID="70C963EF-4CA2-07A3-6B48-394D11135709" is what is highlighted when looking at the code.

```
<div class="loadingPanel" data-aura-rendered-by="27:812;a"></div><span class="loadingMsg" data-aura-rendered-by="28:812;a">Loading report chart...</span></div>
                        <!--render facet: 75:812;a-->
                        <!--render facet: 82:812;a-->
                        <!--render facet: 96:812;a-->
                        <div class="eclair-component-container reportsEclairChart" data-aura-rendered-by="106:812;a" data-aura-class="reportsEclairChart" style="">
                            <div class="eclair-component-chart" data-aura-rendered-by="107:812;a" data-ngname="chart_0" style="width: 464.609px;">
                                <div style="position: relative;">
                                    <div style="z-index: 2; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); width: 464.609px; height: 300px; left: 0px; top: 0px;" class="ps-container" data-ps-id="aee85f92-8bd4-9aeb-b095-68aac4a00821">
                                        <div style="width: 465px; height: 300px;"></div>
                                        <div class="ps-scrollbar-x-rail" style="left: 0px; bottom: 3px;">
                                            <div class="ps-scrollbar-x" style="left: 0px; width: 0px;"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="ps-scrollbar-y-rail" style="top: 0px; right: 3px;">
                                            <div class="ps-scrollbar-y" style="top: 0px; height: 0px;"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <canvas class="chart" style="z-index: 1; position: absolute; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; width: 464.609px; height: 300px; left: 0px; top: 0px;" width="464" height="300"></canvas>
                                    <button aria-live="polite" class="reportsEclairChart ng-button assistiveText">Enable Tab Navigation for This Chart<span class="assistiveText">Enable table equivalent for screen reader users</span></button>
                                </div>
                                <div data-ngname="legend_chart_0" style="">
                                    <div style="position: relative;">
                                        <DIV CLASS="PS-CONTAINER" DATA-PS-ID="70C963EF-4CA2-07A3-6B48-394D11135709" STYLE="">
                                            <div style=""></div>
                                            <div class="ps-scrollbar-x-rail" style="left: 0px; bottom: 3px;">
                                                <div class="ps-scrollbar-x" style="left: 0px; width: 0px;"></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="ps-scrollbar-y-rail" style="top: 0px; right: 3px;">
                                                <div class="ps-scrollbar-y" style="top: 0px; height: 0px;"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <canvas class="legend" style="z-index: 2; position: absolute; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; width: 124px; height: 88px; left: 338.609px; top: 2px;" width="124" height="88"></canvas>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="ng-annotations-container" style="margin: 2px; width: 460.609px; height: 296px;"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="error-div hide" data-aura-rendered-by="108:812;a"></div><span class="eclair-component-alt-text" data-aura-rendered-by="109:812;a">Chart: Priority Campaigns by Response</span></div>
                        <!--render facet: 111:812;a-->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="lightning" data-aura-rendered-by="113:812;a"><span class="reportFooter" data-aura-rendered-by="114:812;a"><button class="slds-button navigateButton uiButton" aria-live="off" type="button" data-aura-rendered-by="118:812;a" data-aura-class="uiButton"><!--render facet: 119:812;a--><span class=" label bBody" dir="ltr" data-aura-rendered-by="121:812;a">View Report</span>
                <!--render facet: 123:812;a-->
                </button>
                <div class="refreshContainer" data-aura-rendered-by="125:812;a"><span class="asOfDate" data-aura-rendered-by="128:812;a">As of Today at 10:​33 AM</span>
                    <button class="slds-button refreshButton uiButton" aria-live="off" type="button" data-aura-rendered-by="137:812;a" data-aura-class="uiButton">
                        <!--render facet: 138:812;a--><span class="assistiveText" data-aura-rendered-by="141:812;a">Refresh</span>
                        <lightning-icon class="slds-icon-utility-refresh slds-icon_container" data-data-rendering-service-uid="393" data-aura-rendered-by="135:812;a">
                            <lightning-primitive-icon lightning-primitiveicon_primitiveicon-host="">
                                <svg lightning-primitiveIcon_primitiveIcon="" focusable="false" data-key="refresh" aria-hidden="true" class="slds-icon slds-icon-text-default slds-icon_xx-small">
                                    <use lightning-primitiveIcon_primitiveIcon="" xlink:href="/_slds/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg?cache=9.28.0#refresh"></use>
                                </svg>
                            </lightning-primitive-icon><span class="slds-assistive-text">Refresh</span></lightning-icon>
                    </button>
                </div>
                </span>
            </div>
```

Comment: Can you provide link to the page or html source?

Comment: It's a salesforce page; unfortunately I can't provide a link to it.  The code above is what I get when I search for a relative xpath using chropath. Is there a product you know of that I can use to get a screen grab of the code?  I know that snipping tool won't work?

Comment: Provide the relevant Html??

Comment: We won't be able to answer this without relevant HTML.

Comment: What’s your expected output

Answer (score 0):

I presume you want to access the span tag contains `Priority Campaigns by Response`

Try following xpath:

```
//span[@class='eclair-component-alt-text'][contains(.,'Campaigns by Response')]
```

OR

```
//div[@data-aura-class='reportsEclairChart']//span[@class='eclair-component-alt-text'][contains(.,'Campaigns by Response')]
```

**Edited**

To access the canvas element try below xpath.

```
//div[@class='PS-CONTAINER']/following::canvas[@class='legend']
```

Comment: If you are looking after something else please provide your expected element you are after?

Comment: Thanks, but I wish it were that easy!  There is a legend embedded in the chart, and there is no string associated with it.  I need the elements of the Legend Legend displays as "Campaign Response" with children "Dispositioned" "Accepted" and "Assigned"(not Campaigns by Response, which is the title of the table).  The line that highlights when looking at the element is  DIV CLASS="PS-CONTAINER" DATA-PS-ID="70C963EF-4CA2-07A3-6B48-394D11135709, which I have put in all caps in the HTML.  Thank you for your help!!!!

Comment: @ALISONHARTLEY : do you mean to access the canvas tag.Please check this is what you after. `//div[@class='PS-CONTAINER']/following::canvas[@class='legend']`

Comment: Actually the above gave me 7 results, so I do need something more unique.  I tried [1] after //div[@class='PS-CONTAINER']/following::canvas[@class='legend'], but it didn't take.  Any more ideas?

Comment: If you want to access the first one try that : `(//div[@class='PS-CONTAINER']/following::canvas[@class='legend'])[1]`